# Need help comparing values of two columns in different WorkBooks

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, range

I'm trying to compare two columns in two different WB let's say A and B which have only column each.
I'd like to msgbox a text whenever the value of cell in the column of A is also in the column of B.

I managed to put values in a variant variable and like now to compare them. I still get a 424 error at the final if statement that checks the correspondance.

Here is the code :

```
Option Explicit

Sub uniformisation()

Dim range1 As Variant
Dim range2 As Variant

Dim Tab1 As Variant, tab2 As Variant 

Dim fichierM As Workbook 

Dim fichierF As Workbook 


Set fichierF = Workbooks.Open("thepath")
Set fichierMission = Workbooks.Open("thepath")

fichierF.Activate
fichierM.Activate

Dim wsF As Worksheet
Dim wsM As Worksheet

Set wsF = fichierF.Worksheets("test")
Set wsM = fichierM.Worksheets("A")

Dim C As range
Dim D As range


Set C = wsFlex.Columns(1)
Set D = wsMiss.Columns(1)


Dim TotalRows1 As Long
Dim TotalRows2 As Long



With wsF
    TotalRows1 = C.Rows(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Tab1 = range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(TotalRows1, 1)).Value
    MsgBox UBound(Tab1)

End With


With wsM
    TotalRows2 = Rows(D.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    tab2 = range(Cells(2, 2=1), Cells(TotalRows2, 1))

    MsgBox UBound(tab2)

End With


For Each range1 In Tab1
For Each range2 In tab2


        If range1.Value = range2.Value Then
            MsgBox range1

            End If

        Next range2
        Next range1




fichierM.Close
fichierF.Close



End Sub
```

Any help would be really apreciated, thanks !

Comment: Tab1 and Tab2 are Variant arrays. range1 and range2 are Variant. They don't have .Value . Try range1 = range2 for condition.

Comment: Merci ! There is no more errors but there is no matches neither. I'm pretty sure the columns are corresponding..

Comment: Okay, I think I found where the problem is, range2 is storing old values. Instead of having "12151" I have the older version "text:12151"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you definitions are all over the place and the code is too long for what it is supposed to do. Also, you have chosen variant which is not really needed for what you want to do. Here is a shorter version that can get you started:

```
Sub CompareTwoColumns()
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim WB1 As Workbook
    Dim WB2 As Workbook

    'make sure both workbooks are open
    Set WB1 = Workbooks.Open("thepath1")
    Set WB2 = Workbooks.Open("thepath2")

    'loop through both columns and compare
    For Each rng1 In WB1.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Columns(1).Cells
        For Each rng2 In WB2.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Columns(1).Cells
            If rng1.Value = rng2.Value Then
                MsgBox rng1.Value
            End If
        Next rng2
    Next rng1
End Sub
```

Comment: @Lispeenium feel free to check this as the answer and upvote :)